# Align textview and progressbar in Android XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I've already tried to align the smallprogressbar with the textview putting them into a linear layout but it doesn't work. Tryed with `android:layout_gravity="left"` but it crashes.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/calibration_1"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNumberWaves"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/calibration_2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIntervalWaves"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/calibration_3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSetValues"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/calibration_5" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/calibration_6" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code updated to match your answer. 
I put the whole code to show what I have.

Comment: Align them how? Side-by-side?

Comment: Yes, i want to put the circle bar next to the textviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

to this:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Without seeing the rest of your source, I don't know if that will mess up other parts of your layout, so you'll probably want to wrap the `TextView` and `ProgressBar` in their own `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/calibration_1"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNumberWaves"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/calibration_2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIntervalWaves"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/calibration_3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSetValues"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/calibration_5" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/calibration_6" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: everything except from the first textview disappeared.

Comment: Wrap the two things you want side-by-side in their own `LinearLayout`, and don't use `fill_parent` on the `TextView`

Comment: Update your question with your modified source, and change your root layout back to `vertical`

Comment: Change your top `LinearLayout` back to `orientation="vertical"`, and the tvNumberWaves `TextView`, make its width `wrap_content`

Comment: the tvNumberWaves and 1° Progress bar are aligned but the other objects disappeared. Updated the code

Comment: Here, I'll just paste on my answer what your layout should be